# How to make 3-Column layout with fluid center (fully utilize space), and variable-length on sidebars

Tags: css

How to make 3-Column layout with fluid center (fully utilize space), and variable-length on sidebars?

The width of sidebars are depends on the length of sentence, so there is no fixed width.

The center column will occupy the rest of free space.

It can be done easily by using "table" tag. I am not sure how to do it in css.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the sidebars going to always be the same size? Or do you want only one to conform to the body's width?

Comment: user1538100 has answered my question. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this help?: http://jsfiddle.net/eNDPG/1/

Comment: see also this answer were I also used the `overflow` property to do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873832/make-a-div-fill-up-the-remaining-width/22719552#22719552