# Div to take up entire remaining width

Tags: css

I have a parent div and 2 divs inside it. First child div is 50px wide and 100% height. Second child div is 100% height and I it to take rest of the width ( 100% - 50px ) how do I do that?

Here is the fiddle that I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/muGty/
Basically I want blue div (right ) to occupy rest of the grey container completely.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: width: calc(100% - 50px);

Comment: Best way to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22719552/759452

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do you mean like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/5jRaY/)?

```
<div id="left">
</div>
<div id="right">
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#left {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background: #f00;
    height: 100%;
}
#right {
    margin-left: 200px;
    background: #0f0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Update:**

You can also use `calc()` property in CSS3, which will ease up this process like

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#left {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background: #f00;
    height: 100%;
}

#right {
    float: left;
    background: #0f0;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 200px); /* Negate the fixed width element value from 100% */
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/5jRaY/155/)

Comment: Just a note ... The element with the "float" property MUST be on top in the markup. Exactly the way Mr. Alien wrote.

Comment: As fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F27sW/

Comment: After trying several solutions, this one worked the best! Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your time   you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Just change your right div to this:

```
.right{
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This isn't very compatible with older browsers. See http://caniuse.com/calc

Answer (score 0):

You could add a 50px margin to `right` and float it.

Answer (score 0):

What about editing your right class to make it look like this :

```
.right{
  float:left;
  height:50px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right:-50px;
  background-color: blue;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also work with an absolute position for the right side column. Consider this example:

```
.parent{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:#888;
    position:relative
}
.left{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:50px;
    background:green
}
.right{
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:50px;
    right:0;
    top:0
}
```

Also see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acjbizar/muGty/1/). Note that you would need to set `position: relative` on the parent container for this to fly.