# Dynamic width to float left div

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-tables

I have two divs in my application. How can I make my left div to fit all space till right div. Right one can be text or image with any width.

```
<div id="header" class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="/Content/images/my_logo.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="logoClient">
        Test Client /*here can be text or image with ANY SIZE */
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

In this example I've done with fixed widths(700px and 200px), but this is wrong, because right one's text is dynamic and I want to left green bar be dynamic too.

http://jsfiddle.net/C5GL6/1/

Another approach with table, table-cell css options... but again... can't make left green bar fit all space.

http://jsfiddle.net/sjfQj/

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529291/div-to-take-up-entire-remaining-width/16529353#16529353)? someone recently downvoted that answer of mine for no good reason

Comment: Remove `width` from both div's

Comment: @Mr.Alien, no, in your example left div has fixed width... I don't want both left and right divs to have fixed width... :)

Comment: @Anup, you really think that I haven't tried such ways?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width size in div

Edited fiddle
   http://jsfiddle.net/C5GL6/2/

```
 .logo {
float: left;
height: 55px;
padding: 10px 20px;
background: #004B35;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width` and add `float:left` to both the divs

```
    .header 
{
    width: 950px;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    display:table
}

.logo {
    height: 55px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #004B35;
    display:table-cell;
}

 .logoClient 
 {
   display:table-cell;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin:0px -10px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #004B35;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    background: red;
}
```

**[DEMO Updated](http://jsbin.com/ORetUbu/6/)**

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ORetUbu/4

Small text is not apperaing in the right part and left part is not fitting all remaining space.

Comment: Use `display:table` and  `table-cell`. here is the demo http://jsbin.com/ORetUbu/6/

Comment: This is going to be good way... But anyway I need just opposite(the red part must be with the size of text(size of "Test Client" or whatever text they will be) and black part must fit remaining space)...