# How to make element occupy remaining width of container?

Tags: html, css

I have an inline div `abc` and another inline div `def`. `abc`'s width is 100px. How can I let `def` appear on the right while `def`'s width is its parent's width minus 100px?

I cannot do width:100%; since `def` would appears next line.

https://jsfiddle.net/h7k87vwx/

```
<div class="abc">abc</div>
<div class="def">def</div>
<div class="ghi">ghi</div>
```

```
.abc {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:lightblue;
    width: 100px;
}

.def {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: ...Just for clarifications, you want the "def"'s width to be the body's width minus 100px?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529291/div-to-take-up-entire-remaining-width

Comment: @frosty yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="abc">abc</div><div class="def">def</div><div class="ghi">ghi</div>
```

CSS

```
.def {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/h7k87vwx/6/

Divs are lined up together to eliminate rendered white space. For an explanation see my answer here:

- [inline-block boxes not fitting in their container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32801095/3597276)

Comment: Didn't even see this answer (or that it was accepted already) before I posted mine... not making line breaks in the document would indeed be another way the eliminate the white space.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an old trick that was commonly used in **holy grail** layout:

```
.abc {
    float: left;
    background-color:lightblue;
    width: 100px;
}

.def {
    padding-left: 100px; /* margin-left also applies */
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

Check out the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h7k87vwx/8/).

Answer (score 1):

Inline-block elements will have an empty space between them, one way to address this is to give them a negative margin. That will make it not be placed below. Another detail would be to keep an empty space in between the different values and the operator with `calc()` otherwise it will not work :

https://jsfiddle.net/t0ecucgw/

```
.abc {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 100px;
}

.def {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    margin-left: -4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do:

```
.def {
    width: calc(100% - 100px)
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h7k87vwx/3/ it won't work. I want "def" to cover the rest of its line, not just cover those three characters.

Comment: I answered this correctly before everybody, yet somehow I am at the bottom :(.

Answer (score -1):

```
.def {
    float:right;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/h7k87vwx/2/)

Comment: This floats it to the right. but I want the width not to be 200px, but (body width - abc's width)