# Fill the horizontal space between left and right floated elements

Tags: css

I found [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4873933/800492) that addresses what I need to do, but it doesn't seem to work perfectly for me. I have sidebar divs floated left and right. I want to stick a div in the middle and fill the space. The technique in that answer works for the left div, but it pushes the right div down to the next line. I threw up [a quick demo on CodePen](http://codepen.io/raddevon/pen/HKgEd) to show the problem.

Can anyone suggest a way to fix this so that all the divs are on the same line?

**Update:** I realize I could do this easily using percentages for all the div widths, but I really need to maintain static widths for the sidebars.

Comment: @Stigma I don't mind that at all. If you'll post your link as an answer, I'll give you credit. Also, could I ask what you the `zoom` and `overflow` properties do for this fix? It seems to work without them, and `overflow: hidden` scares me a little bit. ;-)

Comment: Check out the [CSS layout demos](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/) on Dynamic Drive, specifically [this one](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-31-fixed-fluid-fixed/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be changing the order of your HTML (placing the right sidebar before the left)

```
<div class="page-grid">
    <div class="sidebar right">
        <div>Right Widget 1</div>
        <div>Right Widget 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar left">
        <div>Widget 1</div>
        <div>Widget 2</div>
    </div>
 <div id="content">Content area</div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kHmjd

Answer (score 1):

This is using [an example](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-31-fixed-fluid-fixed/) from Dynamic Drive's [CSS Layouts](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/)

I like this one, especially because it preserves the order of the content semantically. Main content is delivered first, followed by both side columns.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page-grid">
    <div id="contentwrapper">
        <div id="content">Content area</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar left">
        <div>Widget 1</div>
        <div>Widget 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar right">
        <div>Right Widget 1</div>
        <div>Right Widget 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contentwrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 15em;
}
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 15em;
}
.sidebar.left {
    margin-left: -100%;
}

.sidebar.right {
    margin-left: -15em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for another interesting solution. I'll keep this one in mind.