# CSS: force float:left without specifying div width

Tags: html, css, css-float

In the following code (https://jsfiddle.net/6t9n0wuu/):

```css
#cont1 {
  width: 50%
}

#div1 {
  width: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black
}

#div2 {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div id=cont1>
  <div id=div1>a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
  <div id=div2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

the content of `div2` is shifted to a new line.

Is it possible to force `div2` on the top as (i.e. on the same line of) `div1` without specifing its width in CSS?

Comment: What do you actually want the width to be then? The remaining width? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961918/css-fill-remaining-width

Answer (score 1):

see if it works for you :--

```css
#cont1 {width: 50%}
#div1 {width:10px;float:left; border:1px solid black}
#div2 {border:1px solid black;margin-left:12px;}
```

```html
<div id=cont1>
<div id=div1>a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
<div id=div2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</div>
```

You can use flex-box too.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `float:left` of `#div2` and insert `margin-left:10px` to it.

```
#div2 {
  float: left;<---------Remove
  margin-left: 10px;<-----Added
  //more code.....
}
```

```css
#cont1 {
  width: 50%;
}
#div1 {
  width:10px;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#div2 {
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont1">
<div id="div1">a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
<div id="div2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not. Without the width specified one way or another the float will take all the space it needs to display its content. Since its contents is some text it will always shift to another line unless the text width is less then the remaining width of the line. Notice that even if you manage to modify content so that it all fits into one line, once you change the size of the container, e.g. by resizing the window, the float can be moved to another line again.

Thus, your options are:

1. Specify the width, using px, %, calc, whatever.
2. Use some other layout design: e.g. flexbox or grid (check if all the
   browsers you have to support work with them)
3. Use table if what you you want to display is actually some table
   data.
4. Don't try to squeeze everything into one row.

Answer (score 1):

Options to force element to stay on line:

#### Flexbox

To guarantee elements staying on the same line they can be flex-items (unless you specify `flex-wrap: wrap` for container). So making `#cont1` flexbox container prevents your items from moving to new line. Also `float` properties will be ignored for flex-items and it's optional to specify width for your items. Demo:

```css
#cont1 {
  /* become a flex-container */
  /* its children will be a flex-items */
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

#div1, #div2 {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div id=cont1>
  <div id=div1>a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
  <div id=div2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

#### [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

You just specify your container as grid-container and add templates where you specify column width. Demo:

```css
#cont1 {
  /* become a flex-container */
  /* its children will be a flex-items */
  display: grid;
  width: 50%;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

#div1, #div2 {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div id=cont1>
  <div id=div1>a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
  <div id=div2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

For this to work in IE10+/Edge you need to use old syntax and specify cell placement manually unless all grid items will stack in first cell. Demo:

```css
#cont1 {
  /* become a flex-container */
  /* its children will be a flex-items */
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  width: 50%;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

#div1, #div2 {
  border: 1px solid black
}

#div2 {
  -ms-grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id=cont1>
  <div id=div1>a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
  <div id=div2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Table

Just add `display: table` for container and `display: table-cell` for items. Demo:

```css
#cont1 {
  /* become a flex-container */
  /* its children will be a flex-items */
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

#div1, #div2 {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div id=cont1>
  <div id=div1>a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
  <div id=div2>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined width on first `div` you can use `calc(100% - div1Width)` on second `div`. You also need to add `box-sizing: border-box` so that border is included in width of element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cont1 {
  width: 50%
}
#div1 {
  width: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black
}
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div id=cont1>
<div id=div1>a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
<div id=div2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flex property:

```
#cont1 {width: 50%; display: flex;}
#div1 {width:10px; border:1px solid black; flex: 0 0 10px}
#div2 {border:1px solid black; flex: 1 1 auto}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6t9n0wuu/1/

Answer (score 0):

You only need to define your `cont1` as `display: flex;` , that's it.

e.g.

```css
#cont1 {width: 50%; display: flex;}
#div1 {width:10px; border:1px solid black; padding: 0px 20px;}
#div2 {border:1px solid black; padding:0px 20px;}
```

```html
<div id=cont1>
<div id=div1>a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
<div id=div2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</div>
```

here is a fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/talhasheikh/j4o9h1p3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **overflow:visible;** to the container to force float

```css
#cont1 {width: 50%,overflow:visible;}
#div1 {width:10px;float:left; border:1px solid black}
#div2 {border:1px solid black;margin-left:12px;}
```

```html
<div id=cont1>
<div id=div1>a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
<div id=div2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#cont1 {width: 50%; display:flex;}
#div1 {width:10px;float:left; border:1px solid black}
#div2 { border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<div id=cont1>
<div id=div1>a<br>b<br>c<br></div>
<div id=div2>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</div>
```