# Set the width of the parent with the child element

Tags: html, css

I have a challenge that seems simple, but is causing me lack of sleep. Here's what I want to achieve:

1. `.toc` makes the parent go fullwidth, works as intended
2. `.menu` has a narrow parent, works as intended
3. `.searchbar` needs full width parent, does't work

How do I fix my searchbar issue?

My fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/afz7qth3/1/

```
<button data-target="search">search</button>
<button data-target="toc">toc</button>
<button data-target="menu">menu</button>

<div class="site-header">
  <nav class="container">
      <div class="content search">
        <div class="searchbar">
          search
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="content toc">
        Lot of Lorem ipsum [...] elit.
      </div>

      <div class="content menu">
        <ul>
          <li>I am</li>
          <li>a narrow</li>
          <li>width menu</li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
   </nav>
 </div>

.site-header {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  border: 2px dotted black;
  display: table;
}

.content { display: none; }
.content.search { display: table-cell; }

.searchbar {
  width: 100%;
}
```

the `.content` divs are toggled with JS.

I have checked here
[How to make a div fill a remaining horizontal space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032914/how-to-make-a-div-fill-a-remaining-horizontal-space) and here
[CSS fill remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961918/css-fill-remaining-width) and here
[Two divs side by side - Fluid display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display) which did not help me.

Thank you,

Comment: Why is this not simply using `block` in all the places where you are currently using `table`?

Comment: Is reverses the problem, but does not solve it. It works for ```.search```, but then the menu wil be full width as well.