# Side by Side Div With one Fixed size and another width as percentage

Tags: html

I have two Div Tag

I want Make them Side by side

right div fixed at width 200 and left div fill remained area but code dont work

here is my code

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
<div style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 5px dashed blue;position:fixed; "></div>
<div style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 5px dashed red; position: fixed;" ></div>    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [make a div fill up the remaining width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873832/make-a-div-fill-up-the-remaining-width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably not `float` and `position:fixed` your elements. Also inline css is BAD. Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBh5j/). Have a look at `position:absolute;` inside a `position:relative;`

Also I added `box-sizing` to make borders go inside their containers.

**HTML**

```
<div id="div_cont">
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3" ></div>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#div_cont{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    padding-left:200px;
}
#div2{
    border: 5px dashed blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    bottom:0;
}
#div3{
    border: 5px dashed red; 
    min-height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use margin property in css
see here
i have change some properties in your css

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 5px dashed blue;position:fixed; "></div>
  <div style="height: 100px; border: 5px dashed red; position: fixed; margin-right:200px;" ></div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

chk it and have a nice day

Comment: -1 you have `position:fixed;` and `float` on a single `div`. Also inline CSS is bad.

Comment: @haxxxton i know inline css is not good, he put the code with inline css so i have added/edited same code

Comment: You have a responsibility on SO to provide the best practice code :) also you still have `fixed` and `float` on the same `div`

Comment: @haxxxton nice capturing, have a nice day ☺

Comment: @haxxxton you should be aware that not all users like your "favorite" (best/not best) practice. So, you should provide also an inline version. :P

Comment: @SJD, it's not a question of what _MY_ favourite practice is. SO guidelines stipulate to use best coding practices, which for HTML and CSS is according to the w3c. tl;dr - inline styles are bad. also `fixed` and `float` on a single div is redundant and potentially style breaking on certain browsers

Comment: ok guys lets stop chit-chat, and VOTE me UP ;P
every one know whats is the best and good,

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div style="float: right; min-width: 200px; width:20%; height: 100px; border: 5px dashed blue; "></div>
  <div style="float:left; width:79%;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 5px dashed red;" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: -1 for assuming 1% difference is = 5px of border. also inline css is bad

Answer (score -1):

in CSS3 is possible. But be careful with the position:fixed

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; border: solid thin green; ">
<div style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 100px; border: 5px dashed blue; "></div>
<div style="float: left;  width: calc(100% - 220px); height: 100px; border: 5px dashed red; ">
</div>
```