# Three-column HTML flex box: how to set the middle one to get all the remaining space?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Let's say I have a simple three-column layout set up using `display: flex;` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sexyzane/s1j40s42/)). In the left and right columns, I have images with a specified width (`100px` each). In the center column, I have the main content area. This area has an high-res image:

```html
<div id="main-container">

    <div id="left-content">
        <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
        <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
        <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
        <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="center-content">
        <div><img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5560/14080568109_9f33dc7964_o.jpg"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="right-content">
        <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
        <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
        <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
        <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I need to tweak the CSS so that the center column width is, at most, 100% of the available space between the side columns (in other words, it must always be this wide: windowSize-column1-column2). If the window shrinks, I need the center column (and its image) to shrink with it.

```css
#main-container
    {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    }

#left-content,
#right-content
    {
    width: 102px;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: magenta;
    }

#left-content img,
#right-content img
    {
    width: 100px;
    }

#center-content
    {
    }

#center-content img
    {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: SOrry but it renders well in your FIddle. It does exactly what you want.

Comment: Not really: the center is overlapping on the left-column.

Comment: i think you can use width: calc(100% - 200px);

Comment: I'm sorry I truly don't see your problem. I took a screenshot. http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a93atc528

Comment: I increased a bit the width of the columns to make it more clear.

Comment: Confront it with the final one: http://jsfiddle.net/sexyzane/gyhej0jy/

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. You wanted the images in your left and right columns to be fully showed? Nothing to do with the image in the middle column with the baby? :(

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The proper way to do it is with [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex). Set `flex` to `1 1 auto` for the middle column, and `0 0 100px` for the side columns. This makes it so the side columns are always the specified width (or width of content, if set to `auto`), and the middle column takes up the remaining space (growing/shrinking accordingly).

```css
#main-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#center-content {
  /* Lets middle column shrink/grow to available width */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#left-content,
#right-content {
  /* Forces side columns to stay same width */
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

img {
  /* Shrinks images to fit container */
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="left-content">
    <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="center-content">
    <div><img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5560/14080568109_9f33dc7964_o.jpg"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="right-content">
    <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://agevoluzione.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Work-in-progress-1024x603.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I switched to this as accepted after your comment on my previous accepted one. Yours is cleaner and really works best! Thanks!

Comment: Anyway I can avoid fixing the side box width? That will be better than width fixing I think.

Comment: @SkuraZZ yup! The first part of `flex` is a quick way to set [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) and the second part is a quick way to set [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink). So, if you want the sidebars and main content to scale at the same rate based on their content (works well for images only), then use `#left-content, #right-content { flex: 1 1 auto }`. But if you're dealing with text in those sidebars, and not using a width-relative size (eg, `vw`), then you'll also want to set a `min-width` on the sidebars.

Comment: @0b10011 why are you not using `flex:0 0 100px;`? does that not do the same thing as `flex:0 0 auto; width:100px`?

Comment: @klewis `flex: 0 0 100px` is probably the better option. I think when I was answering this ~5 years ago, I was in the process of learning flexbox, so it may have been a beginner mistake or I missed a refactor while getting it to work. Or, there's always the chance I ran into a bug in the early days and that was a workaround. Anyway, you can use either one. Any value specified in `flex` or `flex-basis` overrides `width`, so you can set a different width in a fallback value for browsers that don't support flexbox if you like.

Answer (score 4):

```
#center-content {
    width: calc(100% - 204px);
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sachinvermarip/s1j40s42/1/

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't now that css support basic math! I'll upvote yours!

Comment: @Dr.GianluigiZaneZanettini Not all browsers support this. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler way to achieve what you're asking, and it only requires one line of CSS (`flex-grow: 1`).

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.main-container > div {
  background-color: gray;
}

#center-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">    
  <div id="left-content">
    left
  </div>

  <div id="center-content">
  </div>

  <div id="right-content">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If content of the auto-sized section in `flexbox` is larger than available area it meant to fit, browsers (at least Chrome and Firefox) will NOT respect `flex:1 1 auto;`, and the column/row will take enough space for it's content, not the target container. As a result, the total width/height of all columns/rows in `flexbox` will be more than 100%.

If `flex:1 1 auto;` is coupled with some explicit size, for example `width: 10%;`, then column will be correctly sized to available space, and 10% will be simply ignored. Size in `px` works equally well.

There is something funny going with `overflow: hidden;` being used instead of `width: 10%;`. Result in Firefox is identical, but Chrome cuts out the content on the opposite axis. Even if you set `overflow-y: hidden;` Chrome will cull the content on right hand side (axis `x`).

Here is an example:

```
#center-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the bootstrap 4 solution  [(demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/s0e24jhd/) :

```
<div id="main-container" class="d-flex justify-content-between">

<div id="left-content" class="col-auto">
<p> left</p>
</div>

<div id="center-content" class="flex-fill bg-success">
<p> middle stretched</p>
</div>

<div id="right-content" class="col-auto">
<p>right</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#center-content
    {
        width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: @Sachin Verma solution is very good, but yours is even better! Here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sexyzane/gyhej0jy/

Comment: @Dr.GianluigiZaneZanettini This does not respect the width of the side columns (notice the "work in progress" images being cut off).