# Align element next to floated div and fill remaining space

Tags: html, css

For some reason I can't figure out how to make my `searchContainer` appear to the right of `#logo` and get it to fill the remaining space of `top-header`.

Could anyone help me out? I know I'm so close. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sr563qd0/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="top-header" class="slide">
    <div id="cornerBox">&nbsp;</div>
    <a id="logo" href="/">&nbsp;</a>
    <div id="searchBar">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#cornerBox {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#3CC274;
}
#top-header {
    position:absolute;
    height: 56px;
    width:100%;
    min-width:595px;
    max-height: 50px;
    background-color:#24BD66;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:3;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .23);
}
#logo {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    margin:10px 0 0 15px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:30px;
}
#searchBar {
    border-radius:3px;
    height:35px;
    margin-top:7px;
    background-color:#5ECD8C;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you might need to do is add `margin-left: 165px;` to your `#searchBar` style.  So,

```
#searchBar {
    border-radius:3px;
    height:35px;
    margin-top:7px;
    margin-left: 165px;
    background-color:#5ECD8C;
}
```

I used [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4873933/684617) in formulating my own answer here.  Also, I came up with the value of 165px by summing the 50px width from your `#cornerBox` + the 100px width from your `#logo` + the extra 15px margin around the `#logo`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsjpu9eb/1/).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I had to add a margin.