# Make a div fill up the remaining width without changing the order of the elements

Tags: css

My question is the same as this one: [make a div fill up the remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873832/make-a-div-fill-up-the-remaining-width)

But I don't want to change the order of the divs.

In my specific case, I'd like to have:

```
div float: left; width: 100% - 500px; (i.e. this should take up all the remaining space)
div float: right; width: 250px;
div float: right; width: 250px;
```

I can make this work if I rearrange the order of the divs, but I don't want to do that because on mobile devices I'd like to make the width of all the divs 100% and the order should remain. Is there a way to do this? Is flexbox the only solution?

Comment: width: calc(100vw - 500px) ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `calc()`. Any time the parent `div` changes size, the `100%` will update, and so will `calc()`. This means that it should be full responsive as well.

```
.my-div {
    width: calc(100% - 500px);
}
```

Comment: This only works for about 90% of people: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: I suppose I could just do this in a javascript either way. Thanks

Comment: This seems great actually. It's the UC browser that lowers the percentage so much, but doesn't matter for my target countries

Answer (score 1):

try the following, it is also responsive!

```css
.w-250{
    width: 250px;
    height: 75px;
    
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#r-boxer{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#r-elem{
    width: 99%;
    height: 75px;
    
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="w-250">Width 250px;</div>
  <div class="w-250">Width 250px;</div>
  <div id="r-boxer"><div id="r-elem">Remaining Space</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I want is something like that except r-boxer should be first, and then the 250px boxes