# CSS one div with liquid width next to a floating div that may or may not exist

Tags: html, css, positioning, liquid-layout

I have already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343313/css-set-width-to-fill-of-remaining-area) but I can't get my head to work a solution that fits my needs, because my situation is a bit different and because I am not very good at CSS.

What I have is a div containing three other divs:

- div1 on the left
- div2 centered
- div3 on the right

**The problem is that div2 may or may not exist.**

This is what I currently have:

[image]

But this is what I want:

[image]

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xgwz/15/)

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#div3{
display:block;
background: #CCC;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xgwz/17/

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has really saved me a big headache. I would have never imagined it would be such a simple solution!

Answer (score 1):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/geQqG/16/ and then just copy this code and paste in your dreamweaver and run with firefox browser......

Answer (score 1):

just add  `overflow:auto;` in your div3's css that will work

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you want this

Please remove to width of  `#container`

as  like this

```
#container {

    padding: 5px;
}
```

and over-right properties to this `#div3`  as like this

```
#div3{
    display:block;
    background: #CCC;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now Live demo is http://jsfiddle.net/5xgwz/20/